Logitech H390 Headset yields "Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=2304), cval->res is probably wrong" on Ubuntu 22.04
Good day. My Linux PC drops the Logi headset (Google voice can't see it and Zoom falls back to my PC speaker)
On a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS / kernel 6.5.0-28-generic PC, I get the following output when I just plug in my Logitech H390 Wired Headset:

[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a7a, bcdDevice= 0.15
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: Product: Logi USB Headset
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Logitech
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=2304), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: [7] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = -3840/-1536/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=10496), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:11 2024] usb 1-9: [2] FU [USB Audio Playback Volume] ch = 2, val = -10496/0/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:12 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4352), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:12 2024] usb 1-9: [5] FU [USB Audio Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = -1536/2816/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:12 2024] input: Logitech Logi USB Headset Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.3/0003:046D:0A7A.0078/input/input164
[Mon May 20 12:43:12 2024] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A7A.0078: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech Logi USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input3
[Mon May 20 12:43:12 2024] retire_capture_urb: 2783 callbacks suppressed
[Mon May 20 12:43:15 2024] usb 1-9: reset full-speed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: 1:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x1
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: 2:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x81
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=2304), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: [7] FU [Sidetone Playback Volume] ch = 1, val = -3840/-1536/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=10496), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: [2] FU [USB Audio Playback Volume] ch = 2, val = -10496/0/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=4352), cval->res is probably wrong.
[Mon May 20 12:43:16 2024] usb 1-9: [5] FU [USB Audio Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = -1536/2816/1
[Mon May 20 12:43:17 2024] retire_capture_urb: 3386 callbacks suppressed
[Mon May 20 12:43:22 2024] retire_capture_urb: 2733 callbacks suppressed
[Mon May 20 12:43:26 2024] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 99

Here's what I see when I use a NUBWO HW02 USB Computer Headset (which works perfectly):
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 101 using xhci_hcd
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 1.00
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] usb 1-9: Product: Usb Audio Device
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Generalplus
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] input: Generalplus Usb Audio Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.3/0003:1B3F:2008.007A/input/input166
[Mon May 20 12:45:24 2024] hid-generic 0003:1B3F:2008.007A: input,hidraw7: USB HID v2.01 Device [Generalplus Usb Audio Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input3

Most of the threads I see on the internet with these sort errors in the logs are very old, so posting here. My solution now is to not use the Logi and go with the other, which is fine, but figured I'd see if any solutions. Has anyone had the same issue w/this headset?

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 24.04 with a different device "Arylic Up2Stream USB Audio". In my case, there also issues with volume control, decreasing volume mutes the speaker.

Tossed the subjected one aside.
Purchased "NUBWO HW02 USB Computer Headset with Clear Chat Microphone, Lightweight On-Ear Wired Headset for MS Teams, Skype, Webinars, Call Center and More (Black)" from amzazon:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08P37VLHY/
